# Genexus 18U3 iOS (XCode 14.1). Error en build: "failed to emit precompiled header" y #import "GXExternalObjectBase+GXEOProtocol_GXEOGlobalEvents.h"

Tags: ios, xcode, genexus, build

Luego de actualizar gx a la version 18U3 y xcode 14.1 al hacer build desde genexus obtengo el siguiente error:

> Command: MacTransfer BuildApp /env ".Net Environment" /h
> "Mac-mini-de-Magentha" /ipa True /ipam "Development" /kb
> "GrassiSocios18U3" /m "C:\Models\GrassiSocios18U3\CSharpModel" /o
> "MenuSocios" /p /rb True /sim False /u "magentha" /v "18.0.171579 U3"
> Connecting to Mac-mini-de-Magentha Copying Libraries to
> /Users/magentha/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/18.0.171579_U3/ Synchronizing
> C:\Models\GrassiSocios18U3\CSharpModel\mobile\iOS\MenuSocios\iOS\Genexus
> to /Users/magentha/Documents/Projects/GrassiSocios18U3/dotNet
> Environment/MenuSocios Building IPA sshExec: cd
> /Users/magentha/Documents/Projects/GrassiSocios18U3/dotNet
> Environment/MenuSocios;security list-keychains -s security
> login-keychain | awk '{$1=$1};1' | tr -d '"';security unlock-keychain
> -p security login-keychain | awk '{$1=$1};1' | tr -d '"';security set-key-partition-list -v -S apple-tool:,apple: -s -k security
> login-keychain | awk '{$1=$1};1' | tr -d
> '"';/Users/magentha/Downloads/Xcode
> 2.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -allowProvisioningUpdates -scheme "MenuSocios" -configuration Release archive -archivePath build/MenuSocios.xcarchive SYMROOT=$PWD/build 2>&1 error:
> SwiftGeneratePch normal arm64 Compiling\ bridging\ header (in target
> 'MenuSocios' from project 'MenuSocios') error: cd
> /Users/magentha/Documents/Projects/GrassiSocios18U3/dotNet
> Environment/MenuSocios error: builtin-swiftTaskExecution --
> /Users/magentha/Downloads/Xcode
> 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-frontend
> -frontend -target arm64-apple-ios12.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Users/magentha/Downloads/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.1.sdk
> -I /Users/magentha/Documents/Projects/GrassiSocios18U3/dotNet\ Environment/MenuSocios/build/Release-iphoneos -F
> /Users/magentha/Documents/Projects/GrassiSocios18U3/dotNet
> Environment/MenuSocios/build/Release-iphoneos -F
> /Users/magentha/Documents/Projects/GrassiSocios18U3/dotNet
> Environment/MenuSocios/UserControls -F
> /Users/magentha/Documents/Projects/GrassiSocios18U3/dotNet
> Environment/MenuSocios/UserControls/iphoneos -F
> /Users/magentha/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/18.0.171579_U3 -F
> /Users/magentha/Library/GeneXus/GeneXus/18.0.171579_U3/modules/GeneXus/v4.3.4.171080
> -no-color-diagnostics -g -module-cache-path /Users/magentha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex
> -swift-version 5 -enforce-exclusivity=checked -O -D GXFRAMEWORKS -serialize-debugging-options -enable-bare-slash-regex -empty-abi-descriptor -Xcc -working-directory -Xcc /Users/magentha/Documents/Projects/GrassiSocios18U3/dotNet
> Environment/MenuSocios -resource-dir /Users/magentha/Downloads/Xcode
> 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift
> -Xcc -I/Users/magentha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MenuSocios-ecudhlzymhvrioccnvkoriubfzqn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MenuSocios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MenuSocios.build/Release-iphoneos/MenuSocios.build/swift-overrides.hmap
> -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/magentha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MenuSocios-ecudhlzymhvrioccnvkoriubfzqn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MenuSocios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MenuSocios.build/Release-iphoneos/MenuSocios.build/MenuSocios-generated-files.hmap
> -Xcc -I/Users/magentha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MenuSocios-ecudhlzymhvrioccnvkoriubfzqn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MenuSocios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MenuSocios.build/Release-iphoneos/MenuSocios.build/MenuSocios-own-target-headers.hmap
> -Xcc -I/Users/magentha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MenuSocios-ecudhlzymhvrioccnvkoriubfzqn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MenuSocios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MenuSocios.build/Release-iphoneos/MenuSocios.build/MenuSocios-all-target-headers.hmap
> -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/magentha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MenuSocios-ecudhlzymhvrioccnvkoriubfzqn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MenuSocios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MenuSocios.build/Release-iphoneos/MenuSocios.build/MenuSocios-project-headers.hmap
> -Xcc -I/Users/magentha/Documents/Projects/GrassiSocios18U3/dotNet\ Environment/MenuSocios/build/Release-iphoneos/include -Xcc
> -I/Users/magentha/Downloads/Xcode\ 2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2
> -Xcc -I/Users/magentha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MenuSocios-ecudhlzymhvrioccnvkoriubfzqn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MenuSocios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MenuSocios.build/Release-iphoneos/MenuSocios.build/DerivedSources-normal/arm64
> -Xcc -I/Users/magentha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MenuSocios-ecudhlzymhvrioccnvkoriubfzqn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MenuSocios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MenuSocios.build/Release-iphoneos/MenuSocios.build/DerivedSources/arm64
> -Xcc -I/Users/magentha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MenuSocios-ecudhlzymhvrioccnvkoriubfzqn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MenuSocios/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MenuSocios.build/Release-iphoneos/MenuSocios.build/DerivedSources
> -Xcc -DGXFRAMEWORKS=1 -import-objc-header /Users/magentha/Documents/Projects/GrassiSocios18U3/dotNet
> Environment/MenuSocios/MenuSocios-Bridging-Header.h -module-name
> MenuSocios -disable-clang-spi -target-sdk-version 16.1
> -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/magentha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MenuSocios-ecudhlzymhvrioccnvkoriubfzqn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MenuSocios/PrecompiledHeaders/MenuSocios-Bridging-Header-3b97n3lqlqj84.dia
> /Users/magentha/Documents/Projects/GrassiSocios18U3/dotNet
> Environment/MenuSocios/MenuSocios-Bridging-Header.h -emit-pch
> -pch-output-dir /Users/magentha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MenuSocios-ecudhlzymhvrioccnvkoriubfzqn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MenuSocios/PrecompiledHeaders
> error: /Users/magentha/Documents/Projects/GrassiSocios18U3/dotNet
> Environment/MenuSocios/MenuSocios-Bridging-Header.h:19:9: error:
> 'GXExternalObjectBase+GXEOProtocol_GXEOGlobalEvents.h' file not found
> error: #import "GXExternalObjectBase+GXEOProtocol_GXEOGlobalEvents.h"
> error: ^ error: 1 error generated. error: :0: error: failed to emit
> precompiled header
> '/Users/magentha/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MenuSocios-ecudhlzymhvrioccnvkoriubfzqn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MenuSocios/PrecompiledHeaders/MenuSocios-Bridging-Header-swift_SJ1PKYTHB57A-clang_6NIPRN03VJHB.pch'
> for bridging header
> '/Users/magentha/Documents/Projects/GrassiSocios18U3/dotNet
> Environment/MenuSocios/MenuSocios-Bridging-Header.h' error: 2 errors
> generated. Failed: iOS Compilation Failed: Rebuild MenuSocios

Agradezco cualquier ayuda